# Covert Razor delegate syntax to WebForms

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms, cassette

I am trying to write this style of code from cassette using WebForms. Is this possible?

```
@{
var message = "Hello World!";
Bundles.AddInlineScript(
  @<script>
    if (someTest) {
        alert('@message');
    }
  </script>);
}
```

I haven't managed to find an example of using methods with the `Func<Object, Object>` parameter in WebForms. Or is this because this only allowed by the Razor view engine?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% Bundles.AddInlineScript("if (someTest) { ...") %>
```

Comment: That's a code nugget. It will execute when the aspx is rendered. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Using the string overload is really painful when the inline script is more than a single line, and needs to mix with variables as the aspx is rendered. This is why I am asking if there is another way.